# Mostrar e Esconder

Tags: javascript

Estou com problemas neste código, apesar de ser simples, não estou conseguindo resolver:
O texto "Ver mais!" ao clicar mostra o texto oculto, porem, deveria mudar para "Ocultar" quando clicar nele, e vice versa

Em vez disso, sempre que clica em "Ver mais!" ele muda apenas o do ultimo texto.

```js
var span = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo span')[0];

span.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var conteudo = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo p')[0];

  if (conteudo.classList.contains('mostrar')) {
    span.innerHTML = 'Ver mais!';
    conteudo.classList.remove('mostrar');
  } else {
    span.innerHTML = 'Ocultar';
    conteudo.classList.add('mostrar');

  }

});

var span = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo span')[1];

span.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var conteudo = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo p')[1];

  if (conteudo.classList.contains('mostrar')) {
    span.innerHTML = 'Ver mais!';
    conteudo.classList.remove('mostrar');
  } else {
    span.innerHTML = 'Ocultar';
    conteudo.classList.add('mostrar');

  }

});

var span = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo span')[2];

span.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var conteudo = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo p')[2];

  if (conteudo.classList.contains('mostrar')) {
    span.innerHTML = 'Ver mais!';
    conteudo.classList.remove('mostrar');
  } else {
    span.innerHTML = 'Ocultar';
    conteudo.classList.add('mostrar');

  }

});

var span = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo span')[3];

span.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var conteudo = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo p')[3];

  if (conteudo.classList.contains('mostrar')) {
    span.innerHTML = 'Ver mais!';
    conteudo.classList.remove('mostrar');
  } else {
    span.innerHTML = 'Ocultar';
    conteudo.classList.add('mostrar');

  }

});
```

```css
.conteudo h2 {
  color: cyan;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.conteudo h2 span {
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}

.conteudo p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #313131;
  text-align: justify;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.390);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 15px;
  transition: 4s;
}

.mostrar {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>


  <div class="conteudo">
    <h2>T1 <span>Ver mais!</span></h2>
    <p>TEXTO GRANDÃO AQUI OXIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <h2>T2 <span>Ver mais!</span></h2>
    <p>TEXTO GRANDÃO AQUI OXIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <h2>T3 <span>Ver mais!</span></h2>
    <p>TEXTO GRANDÃO AQUI OXIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <h2>T4 <span>Ver mais!</span></h2>
    <p>TEXTO GRANDÃO AQUI OXIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
    </p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Olhei algumas soluções já postadas aqui no site, porem não consegui resolver no meu código.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
        var span0 = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo span')[0];

        span0.addEventListener('click',function(){
            var conteudo = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo p')[0];

            if(conteudo.classList.contains('mostrar')){
                span0.innerHTML = 'Ver mais!';
                conteudo.classList.remove('mostrar');
            }else{
                span0.innerHTML = 'Ocultar';
                conteudo.classList.add('mostrar');

            }

        });

        var span1 = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo span')[1];

        span1.addEventListener('click',function(){
            var conteudo = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo p')[1];

            if(conteudo.classList.contains('mostrar')){
                span1.innerHTML = 'Ver mais!';
                conteudo.classList.remove('mostrar');
            }else{
                span1.innerHTML = 'Ocultar';
                conteudo.classList.add('mostrar');
                
            }
            
        });

       var span2 = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo span')[2];

        span2.addEventListener('click',function(){
            var conteudo = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo p')[2];

            if(conteudo.classList.contains('mostrar')){
                span2.innerHTML = 'Ver mais!';
                conteudo.classList.remove('mostrar');
            }else{
                span2.innerHTML = 'Ocultar';
                conteudo.classList.add('mostrar');
                
            }
            
        });

        var span3 = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo span')[3];

        span3.addEventListener('click',function(){
            var conteudo = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo p')[3];

            if(conteudo.classList.contains('mostrar')){
                span3.innerHTML = 'Ver mais!';
                conteudo.classList.remove('mostrar');
            }else{
                span3.innerHTML = 'Ocultar';
                conteudo.classList.add('mostrar');

            }

        });
```

Você estava apenas usando a mesma variável pra receber os 4 elementos e então ela ficava apenas com a ultima. Declarei elas como span0,span1,span2 e span3 e funcionou.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).